# How to set this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am going to implement the Calculator type application.
In that I have set the Different button as like below code:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/linear_layout" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <!-- First row Start -->

                <Button android:id="@+id/sevenNumber" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="7" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/eightNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sevenNumber"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="8" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/nineNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/eightNumber"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="9" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>    

                <Button android:id="@+id/acButton" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nineNumber"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="AC" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/brown_button"/>

            <!-- First row Finish -->

            <!-- Second row Start -->

                <Button android:id="@+id/fourNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/sevenNumber" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="4" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/fiveNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fourNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/eightNumber"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="5" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/sixNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fiveNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/nineNumber"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="6" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>    

                <Button android:id="@+id/crearButton" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sixNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/acButton"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="C" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/brown_button"/>

            <!-- Second row finish -->

            <!-- Third row Start -->


                <Button android:id="@+id/firstNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/fourNumber" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="1" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/secondNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/fiveNumber"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="2" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/threeNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/secondNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/sixNumber"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="3" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>    



            <!-- Third row finish -->

            <!-- Fourth row Start -->


                <Button android:id="@+id/zeroNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/firstNumber"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="110dp"
                    android:text="0" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/dotNumber" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/zeroNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/threeNumber"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:text="." android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

                <Button android:id="@+id/doNothing" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/threeNumber" android:layout_below="@+id/crearButton"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:background="@drawable/do_nothing_button" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dotNumber"/>

            <!-- Third row finish -->

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Now, rightnow i have set the first row of Linearlayout as android:gravity="center_horizontal" which contain the button like "7","8","9" and "AC" button. 
But i want it to set autometicaly to fit with the device width.
I think i have to use the weight property. but where and How i have to use it that i dont know So Please Help me regardin it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the weightSum property in your layout tag and in your buttons tag also. Set it to 1 in your layout tag and divide it in the way you want to set your button and set this value to button like if you want 4 buttons to be displayed with equal proportion then 1/4=0.25, set 0.25 to each button tag.

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3aweightSum) and [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2233253e747eeb43).

Comment: Please check the updated question, I have change My Layout fromLinearLayout to Relative for Better use. Now help me for that. . .

Comment: but is there any alternate solution for it ?

Comment: what type of alternate sol are you looking for?

Comment: oK Is your answer is going to help me for relativelayout ??

Comment: Ok Thanks Vineet. I think you are from Ahmedabad. m i right ?

Answer (score 1):

First Set your `LinearLayout` width as `fill_parent`, and remove the `gravity` , and also put `android:layout_weight=1` for each of your children to share the equal width. set `layout_width` parameter of each of the children to `0dp`

Comment: Please check the updated question, I have change My Layout fromLinearLayout to Relative for Better use. Now help me for that. . .

Answer (score 1):

Remove `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` from `LinearLayout`.
Set `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` for `LinearLayout` and `Button`s.
Try setting `android:layout_weight="1"` for every `Button`.

Comment: Please check the updated question, I have change My Layout fromLinearLayout to Relative for Better use. Now help me for that. . .

Comment: What is the better use now? Relative layout can't distribute equal width to it's children...

Comment: Actualy i have to Set the Button Like "+" in this Layout and for that without RelativeLayout it is not possible. So thats why i have use it.